# calling methods and arrays objects Library Book console app C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, methods, visual-studio-2019

My professor wants us to create a reusable class and console app that lists book objects. I got the first part of the assignment where I am supposed to print the books I created, but now I am stuck on the part where I have to modify the data and print again using the same method and then check out two books and print again. I have tried to look at example online and although some of them have helped, none have been able to get me to pass this roadblock.

```
class LibraryBook
{
    private string _bookTitle;
    private string _authorName;
    private string _publisher;
    private int _copyrightYear;
    private string _callNumber;

    public LibraryBook(string booktitle, string authorname, string publisher, int ccyear, string callnumber)
    {
        BookTitle = booktitle;
        AuthorName = authorname;
        Publisher = publisher;
        CopyrightYear = ccyear;
        CallNumber = callnumber;
    }

    public string BookTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return _bookTitle;
        }
        set
        {
            _bookTitle = value;
        }
    }
    public  string AuthorName
    {
        get
        {
            return _authorName;
        }
        set
        {
            _authorName = value;
        }
    }
    public string Publisher
    {
        get
        {
            return _publisher;
        }
        set
        {
            _publisher = value;
        }
    }
    public int CopyrightYear
    {
        get
        {
            return _copyrightYear;
        }
        set
        {
            const int CYEAR = 2019;
            if (value > 0)
                _copyrightYear = value;
            else
                _copyrightYear = CYEAR;
        }
    }
    public string CallNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _callNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            _callNumber = value;
        }
    }
    public bool Avail;


    public void CheckOut()
    {
        Avail = true;
    }
    public void ReturnToShelf()
    {
        Avail = false;
    }
    public bool IsCheckedOut()
    {
        return Avail;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Book Title: {BookTitle}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Author Name: {AuthorName}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Publisher: {Publisher}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Copyright Year: {CopyrightYear}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Call Number: {CallNumber}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"Checked Out: {IsCheckedOut()}{Environment.NewLine}";
    }

}
```

}
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LibraryBook[] favBooksArray = new LibraryBook[5];

```
        favBooksArray[0] = new LibraryBook("Harry Potter and the Philospher's Stone", "J.K. Rowling", "Scholastic Corporation", 1997, "HA-12.36");
        favBooksArray[1] = new LibraryBook("Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secret", "J.K. Rowling", "Scholastic Corporation", 2001, "HA-13.48");
        favBooksArray[2] = new LibraryBook("Tangerine", "Edward Bloor", "Harcourt", 1997, "TB-58.13");
        favBooksArray[3] = new LibraryBook("Roll of Thunder, Hear My Cry", "Mildred D. Taylor", "Dial Press", 1976, "RT-15.22");
        favBooksArray[4] = new LibraryBook("The Giver", "Lois Lowry", "Fake Publisher", -1, "Fk200-1");

        WriteLine($"------LIBRARY BOOKS------{Environment.NewLine}");
        BooksToConsole(favBooksArray);
        WriteLine($"------CHANGES MADE----- {Environment.NewLine}");
        ChangesToBooks(favBooksArray);
        BooksToConsole(favBooksArray);
        WriteLine($"------RETURNING BOOKS TO SHELF------{Environment.NewLine}");
        ReturnBooksToConsole(favBooksArray);
        BooksToConsole(favBooksArray);


    }
    public static void BooksToConsole(LibraryBook[] favBooksArray)
    {
        foreach (LibraryBook books in favBooksArray)
        {
            WriteLine($"{books}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }

    }
    public static void ChangesToBooks(LibraryBook[] favBooksArray)
    {
            favBooksArray[1].AuthorName = "*****The Rock*****";
            favBooksArray[3].BookTitle = "****Totally Not A Fake Name*****";
            favBooksArray[1].CheckOut();
            favBooksArray[4].CheckOut();
    }
    public static void ReturnBooksToConsole(LibraryBook[] favBooksArray)
    {
            favBooksArray[1].ReturnToShelf();
            favBooksArray[4].ReturnToShelf();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What's the question? What code have you tried and what's the error

Comment: What are you trying to modify? Are you trying to create new objects and just pass data through?

Comment: The logic in the `CheckedOut()` and `ReturnToShelf()` functions seems reversed.

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Right now it doesn't look like you've made an attempt. At first glance it looks like your `CheckedOut` (should be named `CheckOut`) and `ReturnToShelf` are mixed up. Returning to shelf should make it available, and check it out should make it unavailable. I'll give you a hint though, these two methods I just mention. You will want to call them on your books. So checking out book 0 would be something like `favBooksArray[0].CheckOut()`

Comment: To change something, just modify the property: `favBooksArray[0].AuthorName = "Somebody Else";`

Comment: I don't need to create new objects just pass the data each time, I also attempted creating a new method to do each of the things described but the teacher said we only use that one method to print all the data every time, which is what is confusing me.

Comment: Remove `static` on field `Avail` and method `IsCheckedOut`. So the flag is for each individual book, and not for all books combined.

Comment: You should only use one method to _print_ all the data - so you are allowed to check out and return books outside of that method, right? It doesn't make sense to call a method `BooksToConsole()` and modify stuff in there. What he probably means is you should call that `BooksToConsole()` more than once.

Comment: And also sorry for any confusion on the questions this is my first time using StackOverflow!